# Orchard breadcrumbs not working with Taxonomies

Tags: orchardcms, breadcrumbs

I'm using Orchard 1.6 and I'm trying to get my breadcrumb widget working for all pages and taxonomies.

For the pages, when a page is selected, the breadcrumbs work as expected:

```
Home > My Page > My Sub Page
```

However, as part of this menu (the main menu, as set up by the 'Default' Orchard recipe), I have added some Taxonomy terms (by adding the 'Menu' part to my taxonomy term content type).

When I view the term page (front end), the breadcrumbs don't render as breadcrumbs, but the full menu instead.

What I would like to know is: How do I make the breadcrumbs recognise the taxonomies and render correctly?

Is there a part I need to add to a specific content type?

For now I need to use the dirty, *dirty* work-around of using a HTML widget; naturally I would prefer an actual solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should file a bug against the Taxonomies project.

Comment: Will do - I just wanted to ensure that I wasn't doing something incorrectly before filing a bug.

Thanks Bertrand!

Comment: For those who would like this issue resolved sooner - vote it up! http://orchardgallery.codeplex.com/workitem/251

Comment: And an easier workaround than a HTML widget (mentioned in the bug ticket @justrhysism linked to above) is to add manual Menu items that reflect the taxonomy terms in the appropriate place in the heirachy

Comment: @Blakomen - Do you mean manually adding the ContentItems to the menu? You're right, that is an easier (better) workaround, however it doesn't work for the listing page. It does mean less widgets though.